# Interaction term in a linear log model

Tags: data-transformation, interaction, linear-model, logarithm

I am using a linear-log model to test whether overseas development assistance and remittances positively affect FDI in cases of good governance and financial market development. Let's say I want to interact the log of net official development assistance received (ODA) with governance. Governance is estimated as a score from -2.5 to 2.5. So I cannot apply the log transformation to governance, but can I still interact the log of ODA with governance? My hypothesis is that ODA will positively affect FDI in cases of good governance.

Comment: Your use of the term "linear log model" is a little confusing for me. I think you mean a linear (OLS) regression model in which some (or all) of the explanatory variables have been transformed by taking the log. I've never heard that term before & I don't think it's standard. You should know that there is a standard term called the "log linear model", which allows us to analyze multi-way contingency tables. You will have an easier time communicating w/ people if you keep these facts in mind.

Comment: If you read gujrati, you will understand that there are different functional forms of regression, where the linear-log model is included.

Comment: Hmmm, I do see that, section 6.6 "SEMILOG MODELS: LOG-LIN AND LIN-LOG MODELS". It's been a long time since I looked at that, I suppose I'd forgotten. Nonetheless, I would avoid using those terms, they really aren't standard in statistics. In particular, people will confuse the log-lin model w/ the log linear model, which are not the same thing at all. I would say, 'a regression model w/ a log transformed predictor' or 'a regression model w/ a log transformed response variable'.

Comment: thank you for the advice. I will change the wordings then. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Linear models (i.e., OLS regression) do not make assumptions about the distribution of explanatory / predictor variables, except that they are known constants.  (To learn more about the assumptions of linear models, it may help you to read this thread: [What is a complete list of the usual assumptions for linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16381/7290))

You are free to transform any, some, all, or none of your variables as you choose.  Some reasons for choosing to do so are listed in this excellent answer by @whuber: [In linear regression when is it appropriate to use the log of an independent variable instead of the actual values?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3530/7290)  The interpretation of log transformed variables is well explained in this thread: [Interpretation of log transformed predictor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18480/7290).

Outside of these issues, the existence of an interaction, or the fact that the transformed predictor is included in an interaction, does not change anything.