# Interpreting intercept for the log model in linear regression in R for small predictor

Tags: r, linear-model, regression-coefficients

I have a dataset. Assume that y is the dependent variable and x is the independent variable. My goals for this analysis is mainly on the following hypothesis:

1. Expecting x=0 to imply y=0
2. Expecting a significant relationship between x and y

To achieve this, I am trying to determine the best transformation of x and y to fit the best linear model in R. So, the final model I got is $\sqrt y$ against ln(x). When I fit the model in R, I obtain the following for the coefficients:

```
  Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.319615   0.028743   11.12 2.93e-10 ***
x           0.150139   0.009959   15.08 9.76e-13 ***
---
```

Questions:

1. I am trying to interpret the Intercept term. Since the p-value is much less than 5% significance level, can I say that the intercept is significantly different from 0? However, this model is undefined for x=0, hence I'm not sure if this interpretation is valid. I was thinking of will it be OK if I were to refit the linear model for smaller x. < Solved >
2. To address the above question, the problem as seen from this model is that I can't test for hypothesis 1. Would be very thankful if anyone could provide some help.

Comment: What I meant was click the [ASK QUESTION](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) at the top, & ask a totally new question, not edit this one. It will also help to say what x & y are (eg, blood pressure, stock prices, etc), why you need a model of them, & why the model should show y=0 when x=0.

Comment: If you can say -- what does $y$ represent?

Comment: @Glen_b y is a ratio of two numbers, each is a count on the number of objects.

Comment: Question continues in a new question thread. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116106/performing-a-linear-regression-on-small-dataset-and-trouble-with-modeling-small

Comment: The denominator of $y$ can occasionally be smaller than the numerator? It seems to behave like there's an upper boundary near 1 (as you'd see with a count divided by a total count - like "proportion of people with brown eyes"), but at least one of the observations exceeds 1. Trying to understand why it's nearly limited to 1 but not quite.

Comment: @Glen_b it is one of the limitation during the data collection process, which is not done by me as the total count is reported by the person but the numerator is reported by the organization. Can just take it as 1.

Comment: @user106113 It would be nice to be able to do so, since that would allow treating $y$ properly - as a binomial count out of a total. However, there's several issues to worry about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intercept term does not refer to when x=0, since your x is actually ln(x).  Instead, the intercept refers to when ln(x)=0, which occurs when the old x=1.  At that point (in the new space), $\hat y$ (i.e., $\widehat{\sqrt{y}}$) differs significantly from 0.

It may help you to read this excellent CV thread: [Interpretation of log transformed predictor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18480/7290).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I totally missed it. If this is the case, how should I test whether at x=0, y is not significantly different from 0?

Comment: Is the point of your analysis to determine if y=0 when x=0? If so, using transformations (eg ln & sqrt) may not be the way to go. Is x=0 within, or close to, the range of x's you have in your dataset?

Comment: It is one of the reality check of the model, that when x=0, y should be close to zero. This transformation seems to be the only one that satisfy the model assumptions on residuals. And for the second question, my x ranges from 0.2 to 200.

Comment: What's wrong with the residuals? Are they non-normal? Is the variance not constant? Is there a curvilinear relationship that isn't being picked up? Bear in mind that when x=0, ln(x)=-infty.

Comment: When i try to fit sqrt(x) or even cube root(x), the residuals have a downward parabolic trend which implies that it is not independent.

Comment: The shape of the residual distribution has nothing to do w/ independence. Why not just regress y on x? What's wrong w/ that?

Comment: Because there is an obvious curve, something that looks like y = sqrt(x) in the original model. Also, regress y on x will end up with non-normal residuals.

Comment: Why not try regressing y on x & x^2? Non-normal residuals usually aren't that big a deal. How far from normal are they & how much data do you have?

Comment: when i perform a shapiro-wilk test on the residuals for y on x, i get a p value of 0.004. Besides, referring to the previous comment, doesn't the downward parabolic trend in the residuals vs fitted plot implies non-independence?

Comment: No, nothing about the shape of the residual distribution has to do w/ independence. Re S-W test, you may want to read [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2492/7290). What is your N?

Comment: Ok, I am confused. What I learnt from uni is that the shape of the residual distribution related to the independence. If this is not true, how do we test independence?

Comment: That would be best as a new question, not buried in comments. What is your N?

Comment: I'm not sure what do u mean by N. I got the following when i run the shapiro-wilk test in R.

"W = 0.8622, p-value = 0.004572". Not sure if this is also one of the reason, my dataset has only 23 points.

Comment: Hmmm, 23 points is pretty tough. It may be hard to determine if the value of y at x=0 is 0. Can you paste your data into your question above?

Comment: I have added the data in the question. Would be grateful for any form of opinions.

Comment: Hmm, not really sure & I don't have a lot of time to explore right now. Why not ask as a new question? Say a little bit about what the data are & what your goals are, etc. then post the data, etc.

Comment: Sorry to take up your time. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: No problem, sorry I wasn't more help.