# Log transformation on variable in percentage units

Tags: regression, data-transformation, percentage

I was working through my STAT course and I got curious about this...
I have seen lot of people use transformations on the variables in regression
especially using logarithms, and usually the transformations don't seem to cause
any particular problem. Would this still be the case if the variable was in
percentage terms? For example, if the dependent variable is body fat percentage
(takes values like 23.4, 5.2, 10.7 and so on), would a logarithmic transformation
cause any problems, or would it still work fine?
If it's okay, how would I then go about interpreting this in Least Squares method (a unit change in the independent variable would be associated with what sort of change in the dependent variable)?

Comment: The logarithm requires the data to be > 0. If your outcome variable is a percentage, a generalized linear model with a logit link [would work](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/proportion.htm). On how to interpret a normal linear regression with log-transformed variables, have a look [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18480/interpretation-of-log-transformed-predictor).