# What is the distribution in Quasi-Poisson regression?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression, quasi-likelihood, poisson-binomial-distribution

For Poisson regression, the assumption is that Y has a Poisson distribution. Is the same assumption true for Quasi-Poisson regression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO**. The quasi-Poisson **is not a distribution* at all, it is an estimation method. There is no distribution model that leads to the quasi-Poisson estimating equations, but still it is found to be useful because it has good asymptotic properties, and is a way to get around the often unreasonable property of the Poisson distribution that the variance equals the mean.

For more information, for instance [Quasi-likelihood/Quasi Poisson](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/314948/quasi-likelihood-quasi-poisson) or [look through this list](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=quasi-poisson+answers%3A1).