# LME - Interpretation of log transformed predictor - Interaction

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, interaction, regression-coefficients

I'm using the library *nlme* to assess longitudinal change in volume of a given brain region (Region X) in a group of patient versus controls. I read on forums (ex: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18480/interpretation-of-log-transformed-predictor)) that log-transforming the VD can help the interpretation of the coefficients. However, I wanted to make sure that I'm correct with my interpretation. Here is my model:

```
model_lme = lme(log(Volume_RegionX) ~ Time*Group + AgeAtBaseline + Gender,
            random = ~1 | SubjectID, method = "REML", data= mydata)
```

Time is in year, `Group` has 2 levels (Patient vs Controls), `AgeAtBaseline` corresponds to the age at the first visit, and `Gender` has obviously 2 levels (F/M). I included subject as random effect. My results are the following:

```
round(summary(model_lme)$tTable,3)

                                  Value Std.Error  DF t-value p-value
(Intercept)                      -2.143     0.464 139  -4.617   0.000
Time                             -0.001     0.012 139  -0.081   0.936
GroupPatient                     -0.289     0.058  67  -4.938   0.000
AgeAtBaseline                    -0.002     0.004  67  -0.593   0.555
GenderM                          -0.119     0.081  67  -1.475   0.145
Time:GroupPatient                -0.104     0.018 139  -5.731   0.000
```

Is it correct to interpret this result by saying: "In RegionX, patients show an annual decrease in volume of 10.4% compare to controls"? Does this interpretation involve anything as regard to the other variables? (example: "... 10.4% compare to controls at the age at baseline of XXX and for Female [which is the reference group for `Gender`]).

Thanks in advance for the help.