# log log interpretation with independent count variable

Tags: regression, interpretation, model, logarithm, variable

Would anyone know how I could interpret the log-log regression with age below?

ln (Income) = const + 0.30 ln(Age) + ut

I don't understand how it is possible to say that if age increases by 1%, income increases by 30%. Age is a unit (count), you can't age by 1% that's why I have trouble interpreting it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Age is definitely *not* a count!  When your child is three months hold, she will be 1% older in about a day.

Comment: The model is closer to being that if age increases by 1%, income increases by 0.3%.  So if you go from age 25 to 26, that would be a 4% increase in age and the model suggests an increase in income of about 1.2% (subject to the $u_t$ term)

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation of the regression coefficient for age is

> A one unit change in log(age) is associated with a change of 0.3 in the expected value of log outcome.

Age is *not* a count variable, you certainly can have fractional age.  You've just not measured it as such.

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation of the coefficient $\beta$ for `Age` is:

> An increase of `Age` by a factor of $k$ is associated with an change
> in `Income` of $100(k^{\beta}-1)\,\%$.

For example: If `Age` increases by 10% (i.e. $k=1.1$), then `Income` is expected to change by $100(1.1^{0.3}-1)=2.9\,\%$.

See also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18480/interpretation-of-log-transformed-predictor-and-or-response) or [here](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqhow-do-i-interpret-a-regression-model-when-some-variables-are-log-transformed/).

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you very much for your answers. 

I wanted to know if the number of children is a variable count and if I can interpret it as you advised ln(Number of children). I also wanted to know if the size of a soccer field in a hectare is a count variable (ln(size)).                                                                                          
I would have said that it is a continuous variable.

I appreciate any help you can provide.