Interpreting an exponentiated coefficient from a regression of a log-transformed outcome when coefficient is < 1
Plenty of stuff online (see here and here) about what to do when you log transform an outcome (exponentiate regression coefficients) and how to interpret the coefficients (1-coefficient*100 = percentage change/difference for one-unit change in predictor).
What I can't seem to find is how to interpret a coefficient less than 1. If it were an odds ratio from a binomial regression an exponentiated log-odds coefficient of e.g. 0.57 would represent a (1-0.57)/0.57 = 0.75 = a 75% reduction in odds of the outcome for every 1-unit increase in the predictor.
My question is can I interpret the regression coefficient from a regression on a log-transformed outcome in the same way? Would the coefficient of 0.57 also represent a 75% decrease in the level of the predictor.

Actually I think @AdamO's answer to this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18480/interpretation-of-log-transformed-predictor-and-or-response covers it. Seems like for coefficients < 1 it is a (1-coef*100)=% change/difference for 1-unit increase in predictor. So for my example of 0.57 it would be a (1-0.57)*100 = 43% reduction in the outcome for a 1-unit increase in the predictor.
